# Querying multiple Django models

Tags: python, django, generic-foreign-key, multi-table-inheritance

I'm looking for some advice on how to execute a query against **multiple** objects and then use them together in a detail view for their related object. Here is what I'm working with right now:

```
-- app/models.py --

class Material(models.Model):
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  slug = models.SlugField()
  description = models.TextField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Category(Material):
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children')

class Content(Material):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class SomeObject(Content):
  # Model specific properties and methods

class SomeOtherObject(Content):
  # Model specific properties and methods
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to display **both** SomeObject and SomeOtherObject together in a Category detail view.  Each of these models will have **different** attributes that make them both unique to each other.  Is this a situation where the **generic foreign keys** are useful?

```
-- app/templates/category_detail.html --

{% block content %}
  <header class="category-header">
    <h1 class="category-title">{{ category.title }}</h1>
  </header><!-- .category-header -->

  <section class="category-items">
    {% for item in category.manager_that_queries_both.all %}
      # Display each item differently depending on the type
    {% empty %}
      "Oops, we couldn't find anything for this category!"
    {% endfor %}
  </section><!-- .category-items -->
{% endblock %}
```

I would like to stay away from **hacks** that are going to be difficult to maintain for the lifetime of this product if possible.  Thanks again for your help guys =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `manager_that_queries_both.all` You can use [Django Model Utils](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-model-utils/).

Specifically the [Inheritance Manager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager).

Your foreign keys would refer to the base class. and then you can query them with

```
Material.objects.select_subclasses()
```

To do things in your templates depending on the type of the object you could implement the filter described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427809/django-template-object-type/12706975#12706975).

Comment: Wow, thank you for the timely response. One thing I'm a little unsure about would be how you would then dynamically display those results in a template depending on the model type retrieved. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: I added a link to a filter that lets you work with the classname (without adding methods to your models)

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeObject(Content):
    # model_specific_arttributes
    is_some_object = True

class SomeOtherObject(Content):
    is_some_object = False
```

Now you can use `if` statements in your template to distinguish between the two types of object and use different templates to display them.